# How to cast a vector to a bus in Simulink

Tags: simulink

Can one cast a vector (array of numbers) to a nonvirtual bus in Simulink? There's a bus to vector block but no vector to bus block. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably need to demux your vector and create the bus with a bus creator block. The purpose of the bus to vector block is "only to replace an implicit bus-to-vector conversion with an equivalent explicit conversion", see [Correct Buses Used as Muxes](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/correct-buses-used-as-muxes.html) in the documentation.